# Cifrado AES-128-CBC con OpenSSL EVP en C

Tags: c, seguridad, openssl

Lo que me ocurre es que hago el siguiente procedimiento para cifrar:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
    handleErrors();

if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, llave, vectorDeInicializacion))
    handleErrors();

if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, nuevoCifrado, &len, textoSinCifrar, strlen(textoSinCifrar)))
    handleErrors();
ciphertext_len = len;

if (1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, nuevoCifrado + len, &len))
    handleErrors();
ciphertext_len += len;

/* Clean up */
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

Una vez ejecutado obtenego dos cosas, la cadena cifrada (nuevoCifrado) y la longitud de dicha cadena (ciphertext_len).

> Es una versión preliminar con merge de varias fuentes, de ahí los
> nombres tan malos y siguiendo formatos distintos de las variables...

Bueno pues la pregunta es que cuando quiero obtener la cadena hexadecimal cifrada hago un:

```
BIO_dump_fp(stdout, nuevoCifrado, ciphertext_len);
```

Obteniendo como salida:
**0000 - 12 b0 76 00 74 78 fc 61-09 70 c4 9e 8d f8 d8 47   ..v.tx.a.p.....G**

Y si hago un:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ciphertext_len; i++) {
    printf("%x ", nuevoCifrado[i]); // Con %02x tampoco funciona
}
```

Aparece esto: **12 ffffffb0 76 0 74 78 fffffffc 61 9 70 ffffffc4 ffffff9e ffffff8d fffffff8 ffffffd8 47**

De repente aparecen 6 'f' delante de algunos octetos, sin embargo delante de otros no.

**PREGUNTA**
¿Cómo puedo quitar esas 'f' y hacer que salga la cadena hexadecimal que realmente quiero: **12b076007478fc610970c49e8df8d847** o que otros métodos puede seguir para conseguirlo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo he conseguido solucionar printeando la cadena de esta forma:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ciphertext_len; i++) {
    printf("%02X", nuevoCifrado[i]);
}
```

Nótese la diferencia entre 02X (solución) y 02x. me ha sorprendido que de esa forma no funcionara pero en cambio consiguiendo la salida en mayúsculas sí.

Comment: Si das una respuesta mejor te ganaras unos buenos votos, la q das ahora esta un poco pobre

Comment: Hecho, pero creo que no daba lugar a mucha confusión, la solución es clara.

Comment: LO q sucede es que las respuestas tienen que darse lo mejor que se pueda, ya que tu duda puede ser la de otro en un futuro, es decir la respuesta no es para ti, es para todos